# How to select and save foreign key object in django views

Tags: django-forms, django-views

I am new to django and was trying to select and save a foreign key object from model ProcessCategory.name in the ProcessGroup view . It works fine in admin, but i couldn't get it to work in my html.

Here's the model, view and html code.
can anyone please help?

**models.py:**

```
class ProcessCategory(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
  desc = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.name


class ProcessGroup(models.Model):

  proc_category = models.ForeignKey(ProcessCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
  desc = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

**views.py:**

```
def ProGrp(request):
p_category = ProcessCategory.objects.all()
return render(request, 'manage_group.html', {'p_category': p_category})

def ProGrp_save(request):
if request.method != "POST":
    return HttpResponse("Method Not Allowed")
else:
    pro_cat = request.POST.get("pro_cat")
    pro_group = request.POST.get("add_pro_group")
    pro_desc = request.POST.get("add_pro_desc")
    
    process_category = ProcessGroup(
        proc_category=pro_cat)
    process_group = ProcessGroup(name=pro_group)
    process_desc = ProcessGroup(desc=pro_desc)
    process_category.save()
    process_group.save()
    process_desc.save()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully Added Process Group")
    return HttpResponseRedirect('add_pro_grp')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('add_pro_grp', views.ProGrp, name='add_pro_grp'),
path('add_progrp_save', views.ProGrp_save, name='add_progrp_save'),
```

]

**HTML**

```
     <select  class="form-control" name = 'pro_cat'  placeholder="Select Process Category">
         {% for each in p_category %}
           <option value = {{each.name}} > {{each.name}} </option>
         {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes that you only want to create **one** `ProcessGroup` with all three fields populated.

I would suggest using [`ProcessGroup.objects.create` [docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#create). This will create and save the `ProcessGroup` for you all in one statement.

This will correctly set the `proc_category` foreign key for you if `pro_cat` is the primary key ([`pk` [docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#the-pk-property)) of a `ProcessCategory` or is an instance of `ProcessCategory`.

```py
process_group = ProcessGroup.objects.create(
    proc_category=pro_cat,
    name=pro_group,
    desc=pro_desc,
)
```

### Edit for HTML solution

The `value=` on the `<option>` is what gets passed to the POST data, so to ensure that the save view is getting a value it can save just change your option tag a little bit. Switch `each.name` to `each.pk` to give your view the value it needs.

```
<option value="{{ each.pk }}"> {{ each.name }} </option>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jacinator. This definitely improved my code readability. But I'm still not getting the foreign key objects in the html select field. Did i miss anything there?

Comment: @Teby, that should be a fairly simple solution. I didn't realize that was your issue when I read through your question prior, but it makes sense to me now.